# Laravel 5.4: User permissions customized by section

Tags: php, laravel-5, authentication, permissions

I am creating a management panel where you should be able to assign each user permissions to access and manage each of the sections.

In the **users table**, I have the following:

```
id
name
password
news
reports
events
documents
communities
videos
tags
active
created_at
updated_at
```

The fields: **news, reports, events, documents, communities, videos** and **tags**, are tinyint (1) fields with value "0" or "1". If the value is equal to "1", the user has permission; and if it is equal to "0", the user does not have permission. These fields correspond to each one of the sections of the panel.

I have made the basic access and authorization connection successfully, but now I do not know how to check access permissions for each section according to what the user has or not restricted. I have seen some permission packages and user roles, but they do not do what I need. Some help?

In **LoginController** I have:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = 'panel.index';

    public function username()
    {
        return 'name';
    }

    public function acceso(Request $request)
    {
        $data['name'] = $request->name;
        $password = $request->password;

        if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $data['name'], 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return view('panel.login.index', compact('data'));
        }
        else {
            return back()->with('message' , 'Ups! El nombre o la clave no son correctos.');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return view('panel.index');
    }

}
```

In each controller I have put the **__construct()**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

In **routes** I have:

```
// Login
    Route::resource('login', 'LoginController');
    Route::get('/panel', 'LoginController@index');
    Route::post('login/index', ['as' => 'login.acceso', 'uses' => 'LoginController@acceso']);
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@index']);
```

And this is in the **view** to login:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'login.acceso', 'class' => 'form', 'id' => 'acceso_form']) !!}
    Bienvenido al Panel de Gestión.</br>
    Por favor, introduce el nombre de usuario y la clave:<br><br>

    {!! Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'usuario']) !!}
    {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'clave']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('ACCEDER', ['class' =>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{{ csrf_field() }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="dialogo_requerido" style="width: 80%; margin: 2em 10% 0 10%">{{ session()->get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Usually what you'd do in this situation is assign a middleware around the routes that require specific access, check the User that is logged in via the middleware and see if they have the correct permission. If they don't, you redirect them somewhere. Also, and out of curiosity, what is it that authentication packages don't accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I do not know very well how to do what you say, I'm a little lost with this, I'm going to get to see if I take it out. Anyway, if you have time to show me a sample, it would be very appreciated. About the packages, the information I have seen refer to user roles (administrator, editor, etc.) but I have not seen that permissions can be given by specific sections for each user; That's why I've undone them.

Comment: Fair enough, and understandable. If you can, take a look at `Sentinel`, specifically how it handles permissions: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#permissions. It has both roles and user permissions, so there's some inheritance going on. I can post an example of how middleware works; give me a sec for that.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to take a look while. This from the users is a bit difficult for me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle permissions-based access, it's possible to use Laravel's middleware function to handle this. First, let's create a middleware `CanAccessReports` (`app\Http\Middleware\CanAccessReports.php`):

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CanAccessReports {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {

        $user = Auth::user(); // or Sentinel::getUser(), etc

        // Check if the User has access to `reports`, redirect otherwise
        if($user->reports == 0){ // or if($user->hasAccess(["reports"]){ ... }
            return back(); // or redirect("/");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Next, assign this as available to routes by adding it to the Kernel: (`app\Http\Kernel.php`)

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    "canAccessReports" => \App\Http\Middleware\CanAccessReports::class
];
```

Note, you could also assign this to an existing middleware group, or create your own. Depends on how you want to use it. Have a read of https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware if you need more info.

Lastly, to use this in your App, assign it to a route/route group: (`routes\web.php`):

```
...
// Assign to a single Route
Route::get("/reports/exampleReport", "ReportsController@example")->middleware("canAccessReports");

// Or assign to a Route Group
Route::group(["prefix" => "reports", "middleware" => "canAccessReports"], function(){
    Route::get("/exampleReport", "ReportsController@example");
});
```

With either of these methods, if an Authenticated User tries to access `http://yourApp/reports/exampleReport`, and they didn't have the permission for `reports`, they would be redirect back. You could use `session()->flash("Access Denied");` to pass a message back, or other methods.

I've included how it would work with your current setup (column on `users` for each permission, and `Sentinel` functions in the middleware as an example too. Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, Tim. I'm going to integrate it into my app and I'll tell you ;)

Comment: Dear Tim, I have an error: ReflectionException in Container.php line 721: Class canAccessReports does not exist. I'm going to edit my question to detail what I've done…

Comment: Confirm the name of the file is correct where it needs to be, `canAccessReports`, lower-case "C" should only be in `Kernel.php`; everywhere else it should be `CanAccessReports`, uppercase. Then, if still persisting, run `composer dump-autoload` to reload available classes.

Comment: Confirmed, all the names are correct. Only in the Kernel and when I call the middleware in the routes I use the lowercase "c". And I run composer dump-autoload, but still giving error. I run before too.

Comment: Ah I see it. You named your middleware in `Kernel.php` incorrectly: `canAccessReport` (missing the "s")

Comment: Missing an "s" in routes! It works perfect, I will finish integrating it. Thanks Tim!

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question and deleted that part to leave it clean for another that comes ;) Have a nice day!